# How to get innerHTML of every li element of ul list - without Qj?

Tags: javascript

Code looks like this:

```
<html>
<body>

<ul>
<li>1</li>
<li>2</li>
<li>3</li>
<div><div>
<ul>
<li>4</li>
<li>5</li>
</ul>
</div></div>
</ul>

<script>
console.log(document.querySelectorAll('ul > li'));
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

would like to get 1, 2 and 3 `innerHTML`. With Qj it was `$('element').html();` but I dont wan't to use QJ.

Comment: What is Qj? Do you mean jQuery?

Comment: You have to write a loop  or use a looping function like `.map()`.

Comment: yea Qj = jQuery, @Barmar could you give an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a looping function to process each element.

```js
console.log(Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("ul > li")).map(el => el.innerHTML).join(" "));
```

```html
<ul>
<li>1</li>
<li>2</li>
<li>3</li>
<div><div>
<ul>
<li>4</li>
<li>5</li>
</ul>
</div></div>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks! BTW is this possible to use something else then querySelectorAll? Hmmm something like UL childNodes that match LI element?

Comment: You can use two nested loops with `.getElementsByTagName` and `.childNodes`.